# Jenkins git authentication fails while using private key/permission denied

Tags: git, jenkins, repository

Currently I'm trying to setup Jenkins and I have a problem with integration project at Jenkins with it's repository on git server.

As a connection credentials I've set a username and a private key which I put directly into textbox.
Well, I don't know why, but everytime I try to connect to the GIT repository I get 128 response code. Key and address is OK, because I'm using these parameters to commit changes in my code to this repository (I'm creating session via PuTTy and then commit via TortoiseGit).

Below is my error response from a server:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git_repository_url.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So far my only thought about that is a lack of Jenkins process system permissions but I'm not actually sure what for it'll need such ones just for repository connection.

Did anyone had similar problem with Jenkins to the one above?

Comment: Is the git_repository_url.git an ssh one? (similar to `git@yourserver:yourrepo.git`?)  Do you have a Jenkins public key publish on the git server side?

Comment: Yes. it's one with ssh, something like:
ssh://git@git_and_so_on.git
The only key saved on git server is one from pair at this private key I'm using to connect to repository and it's working well.
Does Jenkins has it's own public key which I should put into git server?

Comment: Does Jenkins has it's own public key which I should put into git server? It should, if it needs to be authenticated by the git server. Is your git server a GitLab one?

Comment: It should be authenticated by the git server via my generated public/private keys pair which it takes from credentials.
Thanks for advice. I'll check if Jenkins has it's own key needed at authentication.

Comment: "my generated public/private keys pair which it takes from credentials."... which credentials?

Comment: Well. Jenkins has credentials configuration panel. It allows few possible authentication methods for every new credential. One of them is username and private key which I'm using. Public key from pair is saved on git server.

Comment: OK I see mine (ssh private key) indeed. Is your Git server a GitLab one?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because I don't have access to admin's panel on git server, but I think it's not GitLab.